# Rails - belongs_to association not updating foreign key

Tags: activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :publication

  before_create :bind_project

  private
    def bind_project
      self.create_project
    end
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :publication, :inverse_of => :project
end
```

According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-create_association) when creating a new `Publication` the `publication_id` attribute on the `project` model should be set by the `create_project` method.

Why it does not happen?

This is what I see on `bind_project`:

- `self.project_id` is set correctly
- `self.project.publication_id` is `NULL`
- `self.project.publication.id` is set correctly

The database reflects this also: the `projects.publication_id` column is `NULL`.

Comment: Project shouldn't have a publication_id at all

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit strange, that you try to access the `create_project` method in a `before_create` callback. Typo? An `after_create` callback seems to be more appropriate.

Moreover: What for do you need the `publication_id` attribute on the `has_one` side of an association? There only needs to be one `_id` attribute on the `belongs_to` side.

Addendum to my first paragraph: As I see it, you are trying to use Rails magic on the associated object (the `create_project` method) before the actual base object is finished being created. Although this might work, this would be my first point to investigate.

Comment: Im pretty ashamed of my question. As you and Frederick Cheung say, I don't need `publication_id` as a column neither as an attribute.

On the other hand, can't realize why its strange using `before_create` instead of `after_create` for `create_project`. Can you explain on it?

Comment: Nonsense, shit happens, to all of us! An attempt to explain edited into answer.